# How to embedd pdf file to data table using in shiny app?

Tags: html, r, pdf, shiny, dt

Lets say I have a simple shiny app that returns `DT` table:

```
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now, I have pdf documents that I want to add as embedded pdf in last column. 
Lets say than names of pdf files are myfile.pdf, myfile2.pdf, myfile3.pdf...
I want the table to look something like

```
column1...|columnn|pdfdocument
A         |b      |myfile.pdf
C         |d      |myfile2.pdf
...
```

I tried with:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  mtcars <- cbind(mtcars, tags$embed(srce = "myfile.pdf"))
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  })
```

but it returns:

```
cannot coerce class ‘"shiny.tag"’ to a data.frame
```

How can I embed downloadable pdf file to DT dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
First, I download pdf document from API. Then I copy that document to `www` folder:

```
file.copy("pdfContent", paste0("www/", "pdfPath"))
```

After that I have created links with pdf content:

```
pdf_links <- paste0('<a href="', "pdfpath.pdf,' target="blank">PDF</a>')
```

and add this to DT table.

Comment: can you please share the final working code ?